# Vue js, axios: 403 wrong access token even though its the right one

Tags: vue.js, axios

My Vue application has an email subscription field that has a submit button that POSTS the email to my API. I am getting the following error when I click the submit button:

```
{"meta":{"status":false,"error":{"code":0,"message":"Wrong access token.","customer_message":""}},"data":[]}
```

I am 100% sure that my API key is correct and so is the link to my API.

This is the code I have:

```
<template>
<div class="subscription">
      <div class="email_field">
        <input
          class="email_subscription"
          type="email"
          v-model="postEmail"
          name="email_subscription"
          placeholder="Email address here"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="submit_email">
        <input type="submit" class="button_submit" @click="submitEmail()" value="Submit" />
      </div>
</div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      postEmail: null,
      language: "en",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    submitEmail() {
      axios
        .post(
          "https://my_api.com/registrations?access_token=my_api_key",
          {
            language: this.language,
            user_email: this.postEmail,
            auth: {
              username: "username",
              password: "password"
            }
          }
        )
        .then(response => {
          // console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {});
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I would highly appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you check the request in the browser's console? You should also consider not sending the API key and password as plaintext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the auth section and it worked! The auth section was this:

```
auth: {
              username: "username",
              password: "password"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add header object

```
 methods: { submitEmail() {   axios
        .post(
          "https://my_api.com/registrations?access_token=my_api_key"
          {
            language: this.language,
            user_email: this.postEmail,
            auth: {
              username: "username",
              password: "password"
            }
          }, 
{  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'JWT fefege...' }  } )  .then(response =>  { // console.log(response); })  .catch(function(error) {}); } }
```